# Problem with itemize indentation in minipage in tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, indentation, itemize, minipage

How could I disable the indentation of the items here:

[image: items indented]

The MWE is this (compiled with pdflatex):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\pdfpagewidth=148mm \pdfpageheight=210mm % for PDF output
\paperwidth=148mm \paperheight=210mm     % for TikZ


\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,y=0.80pt,x=0.80pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,anchor=north west]

  \begin{scope}[shift={(0,0.34461553)}]% layer1

  \path[fill=blue] (10,10) node[below right] (text3134) {%
    \frame{%
    %\parbox{150pt}{%
      \begin{minipage}{150pt}%
        \begin{itemize}%
          \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
          \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
          \setlength{\itemindent}{0em}%
          \setlength{\parindent}{0em}%
          \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
          \setlength{\marginparsep}{0em}%
          \leftmargin=0em%
          \itemindent=0em%
          \labelsep=0em \labelwidth=0em%
          \item[\textcolor{red}{\textbullet}] Hello
          \item \frame{world!}
        \end{itemize}%
      \end{minipage}
    %}%parbox
    }%frame
  }%path
  ;

  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to use `enumitem`. This is your code modified accordingly.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,enumitem}


\begin{document}

\pdfpagewidth=148mm \pdfpageheight=210mm % for PDF output
\paperwidth=148mm \paperheight=210mm     % for TikZ


\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,y=0.80pt,x=0.80pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,anchor=north west]

  \begin{scope}[shift={(0,0.34461553)}]% layer1

  \path[fill=blue] (10,10) node[below right] (text3134) {%
    \frame{%
    %\parbox{150pt}{%
     \begin{minipage}{150pt}%
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt]%
%           \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
%           \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
%           \setlength{\itemindent}{0em}%
%           \setlength{\parindent}{0em}%
          \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
%           \setlength{\marginparsep}{0em}%
%           \leftmargin=0em%
%           \itemindent=0em%
%           \labelsep=0em \labelwidth=0em%
          \item[\textcolor{red}{\textbullet}] Hello
          \item \frame{world!}
        \end{itemize}%
      \end{minipage}
    %}%parbox
    }%frame
  }%path
  ;

  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of using `\frame` you can just put `node[below right,draw,rectangle] (text3134) {....`.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @HarishKumar - works dandy fine `:)` - cheers!